# Mysql connect 3 tables with if case or maybe Join?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables and I have to connect them. The main table that consist all records for **group trainings** or **individual trainings** is called blocked_dates. The group trainings can be recognized if group_id > 0. If group_id = 0 than reservation_id shows that the reservation is for individual training..
I must get somehow the training id and the training date from either table **group_member_reservations ** or table  **reservations**

Table blocked_dates

[image]

When blocked_dates.group_id > 0 the query must get id, training_date  from table
`group_member_reservations for all records that have :

```
group_member_reservations.bdid = blocked_dates.id and 
blocked_dates.blocked_date= group_member_reservations.training_date and 
blocked_dates.group_id = group_member_reservations. group_id and 
group_member_reservations.anulated = “0” and 
group_member_reservations. paid_status = “not_paid”
```

The table that has all records for group trainings is called **group_member_reservations**and has the following structure

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbE9C.png]

When blocked_dates. reservation_id > 0 the query must get id, date from table reservations for all records that have:

```
reservations.id = blocked_dates.reservation_id and 
reservations.status = “1” and 
reservations.paid_status = “not_paid”
```

Here is the structure of table reservations

[image]

Can I request the needed information with one query. I hope I had explained correctly the desired results. Thanks for your time in advance

### *** Here are the tables structure:

### -- Table structure for table `blocked_dates`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `blocked_dates`;
CREATE TABLE `blocked_dates` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `reservation_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `blocked_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `anulated` enum('0','1') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

### --
-- Table structure for table `group_members_reservations`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `group_members_reservations`;
CREATE TABLE `group_members_reservations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bdid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `group_id` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `training_date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `paid_status` enum('paid','not_paid') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'not_paid',
  `anulated` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

### --
-- Table structure for table `reservations`

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `reservations`;
CREATE TABLE `reservations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 COMMENT '1-open;2-canceled_by_customer;3-canceled_by_admin',
  `paid_status` enum('paid','not_paid') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'not_paid'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Insert statement

```
INSERT INTO `blocked_dates` VALUES(1, 2, 0, 1, '2021-08-01', '0');
INSERT INTO `blocked_dates` VALUES(2, 0, 1, 0, '2021-08-01', '0');
INSERT INTO `blocked_dates` VALUES(3, 0, 2, 0, '2021-08-01', '0');
INSERT INTO `blocked_dates` VALUES(4, 3, 0, 2, '2021-08-01', '0');


INSERT INTO `group_members_reservations` VALUES(1, 2, 1, '2021-08-01', 'not_paid', '0');
INSERT INTO `group_members_reservations` VALUES(2, 3, 2, '2021-08-01', 'not_paid', '0');



INSERT INTO `reservations` VALUES(1, 2, '2021-08-01', 1, 'not_paid');
INSERT INTO `reservations` VALUES(2, 3, '2021-08-01', 2, 'not_paid');
```

COMMIT;

Comment: Unclear. Start from sample data (as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, in textual form available for copypasting - or create online fiddle). Then formulate complete rules set. Then show desired output. Then provide detailed explanations for each output row - how it is obtained, why so, what rules and in what order were applied. PS. And do not use `“”`, use common quote chars `'` or `"`.

Comment: @Akina Each of the tables above are shorter that the actual structure because the other fields may confuse the reader. What you suggest was easier for me but could confuse the reader. It cost me much more time to create the above structure and example just to point your attention to the important fields.. Sorry if this is not enough to get an idea of the casus

Comment: *Each of the tables above are shorter that the actual structure because the other fields may confuse the reader.* Simply remove them while creating a fiddle.

Comment: @Akina Just added create procedure for table structure. I will now try to add some rows for examples

Comment: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=03231d5aefa1e74a5f104ed351bbc023) with your structures. Add sample data, adjust server version if needed, and post the link, then show desired output with detailed explanations.

Comment: @Akina just added insert statement to the question and tried to run query in your fiddle but nothing happaned :(

Comment: [fiddle with the data](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=110a47daccd52a5e1d128ba640425d3e). Now show desired output with detailed explanations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235650/discussion-between-europeuser-and-akina).